# How to avoid There Was a Problem Reaching This App Error When Launching Pinned App from Teams Desktop Client

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Starting ~2 weeks ago (around Sep 14th, 2021) many of our customers have started to report problems launching any PINNED apps from their desktop teams client.   Web chat Teams client can launch pinned Apps fine.  Apps are pinned as part of a set up policy in Teams Admin Portal, in this case a Global Set up Policy.

Jira App is shown below as an example but it is happening for all pinned aps, at least ones with a chat tab (bot).

If you click on the ... below the app list on the left navigation rail and launch the app in that manner the error goes away.

The error does not prevent messaging to and from the app, just that it stop the users since they believe there is a problem.  Clicking on retry does not do anything.

Are there any recent changes to Manifest files that may need to be addressed to avoid this pop over error?

Previous articles from Feb had recommended disabling Loading Indicator in Manifest files. That does not seem to have any impact on this situation.

[image]

Comment: Did any of your customers report this to Microsoft support , and if so do you know are there any tickets open ?

If this is an operational outage for you or your customer(s) then Microsoft support would be the recommended route

Comment: An Incident has been raised already for this issue, and the concerned team is looking into it.

Comment: Just to add, our apps are also facing this error @Meghana-MSFT and customers are  raising support requests assuming something is going wrong. Pls let us know if you have a timeline for the fix.

Comment: Our app is also facing the same issue on teams desktop app

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being tracked on github. Please visit this for updates on [Problem reaching the app](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4249) issue.