# Teams Conversation window displaying error message will not go away

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a C# botframework bot that I have been debugging and at some point received the error: **There was a problem reaching this app -Retry-**.  Pressing **-Retry-** does nothing and now that error permanently takes up half of the chat window with the bot.  I've read other people experiencing this with tabs pointing to a fix within the manifest file changing the loading indicator but this does not change the behavior.  There is another issue with pinned apps: [How to avoid There Was a Problem Reaching This App Error When Launching Pinned App from Teams Desktop Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374587/how-to-avoid-there-was-a-problem-reaching-this-app-error-when-launching-pinned-a) ... but no apparent resolution yet.  Anyone have suggestions?  Thanks!
[image: Error]

[image: Card in Web Client (good)]

[image: Card In Desktop Client (bad)]

Comment: Thanks [prasad-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16356296/prasad-msft).  One note about the workarounds that hopefully gets picked up in the fix.  This issue completely messed up the  way that tables were displayed in the app and going to the pop out 1:1 chat did not seem to help this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ongoing issue in Teams that is causing some users to see an error ("There was a problem reaching the app") when navigating to the bot personal app from flyout. The fix is expected to begin rolling out on October 4th and reach 100% by October 8th.

Tracker: [#4249](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4249)

Suggested workarounds for this issue: utilizing the app in web browser, popping out the 1:1 chat, or using mobile Teams client.